# Layout issue with TextInputLayout as part of Constraint Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I've created a text input with the help of the design support library but it behaves strangely inside the constraint layout I placed it in. The code below is how I wish the widget to be displayed and it initially displays correctly both in the design-builder and on the device. However, if I select the `TextInputLayout` (in either the design or blueprint layout) the `EditText` has it's `layout_width` modified from `match_parent` to `0dp` causing it disappear.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/textInputLayout"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/activity_login"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/activity_login"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/activity_login"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/activity_login"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:hint="@string/email"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="11dp"/>
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

[image: The state of the layout after the EditText have changed]

Comment: What's your problem then? Seems like this is working correctly.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not. The layout_width property EditText keeps being set to `0dp`. This occurs each time a sibling or parent view is edited.

Comment: Yes, that's the accurate behaviour. The `EditText` width is currently set as `match_parent`. So whenever a change to the parent layout should effect the `EditText` inside it.

Comment: If you are using the  `ConstraintLayout` you probably need to put your  `EditText` at the same level as `TextInputLayout` and set its constrains accordingly. Then in the code you should be able to do whatever is required to "bound" `EditText` to the `TextInputLayout`

Answer (score 3):

I figured I'd come back and provide a solution since this is still left open.

The reason I was seeing the EditText views were behaving abnormally in the TextInputLayout is because they shouldn't be there in the first place. The TextInputLayout is part is the design support library and gives developers an easy way to build dynamic labels and error messages for text fields in a manner that is consistent with the Material design spec. However, they have a TextInputEditText as a child, not EditText.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/emailLayout"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:labelFor="@+id/email"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/activity_login"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/activity_login"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/activity_login"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/activity_login"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:hint="@string/email"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="11dp"
        />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: It's really is annoying that in Android studio when we drag the TextInputLayout we get EditText inside it but according to [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout.html) one could see that they support android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText instead of EditText

Answer (score 0):

**In my case i just put the below line it worked fine**

`android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
android:imeOption="yourAction"`

Answer (score -4):

```
tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
```

Include these lines in `textInputLayout`.

Comment: These lines only influence the layout editor preview, not the actual app code.